# cordova: module "cordova/plugin/SmsInboxPLugin not found

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am trying to use the sms-reception-plugin.
I created the `plugin.xml`

```
<plugin xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0"
       id="cordova.plugin"
  version="0.1.2" >

<name>SmsReception</name>
<description>Cordova SmsReception Plugin</description>
<license>Apache 2.0</license>
<keywords>cordova,smsreception</keywords>


<js-module src="www/SmsInboxPlugin.js" name="cordova.plugin.smsplugin">
    <clobbers target="cordova.plugin" />
</js-module>

<!-- android -->
<platform name="android">
    <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
        <feature name="SmsPlugin">
          <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.plugin.SmsInboxPlugin" />
        </feature>
    </config-file>

    <source-file src="src/android/SmsInboxPlugin.java" target-dir="src/org/apache/cordova/plugin" />
    <source-file src="src/android/SmsReceiver.java" target-dir="src/org/apache/cordova/plugin" />

</platform>

</plugin>
```

Then i used this code in .html
`var smsPlugin = cordova.require('cordova/plugin/smsplugin');`
still its showing the error `Uncaught module cordova/plugin/smsplugin not found`
I created the `plugin.xml` as described in [here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/plugin_ref_spec.md.html#Plugin%20Specification).
If any body have any idea help me.

Comment: Where is the _plugin.xml_ located and how did you install it to your app project?

Comment: If you use CLI then only you can see the `plugin.xml`. Its located in `/plugins/plugin-name` directory. @sanfor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check for the `name` property in the `js-module`. I have this problem while using the same plugin, it should me same as the Plugin name.

If it doesn't work switch to other one [PhoneGap-SMS](https://github.com/asanka-x/Phonegap-SMS/tree/0758bcc7346e5bbbf6e02774ae44e00ed2f8a922) Plugin. This will be useful.

If you will read this document about the plugins in cordova you will get the idea, how these plugins are built. [Cordova Plugin Documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/plugin_ref_spec.md.html#Plugin%20Specification)

Answer (score 2):

Try the below tutorial,
and see if you followed as desired in int.

http://devgirl.org/2013/09/17/how-to-write-a-phonegap-3-0-plugin-for-android/